# How to get ctags to pick up functions in a .h file?

Tags: macos, ctags

I am using Exuberant Ctags 5.7.  I am trying to build a tag database for CGContext.h with:

```
tags /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGContext.h
```

The resulting tags file has no functions included in it.  It only has 75 lines for types, and enums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add --c-types=+p (now --c-kinds).

Comment: --c-kinds=+p works too.  I couldn't find documentation for --c-types.

Comment: Sorry, old version. Corrected.